# I am unable to open a game which can run in ubuntu but is not running

Tags: games, 19.04

Using Ubuntu 19.04.

The problem is that i installed the  game bombsquad on Ubuntu by using  the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo +x bombsquqad

sudo a+x bombsquad

sudo sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib libc6-dev-i386 dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0
```

But the game did not run 
I opened it with other applications like archive manger etc. it reacted and the archive manager app and etc. opened but when i tried to open with disk image mounter(which i think is the default one) the game doesn't opened and the disk image mounter does not opened.Just After using disk image mounter to open the game the only difference was that bombsquad selected(5.7 MB) was shown in the right down corner of the screen. Also in bombsquad properties "allow the executive file as program" was ticked or you can say selected . i think there i some problem in disk image mounter

A similar thing happened with my brother he was also having Ubuntu 19.04 and when he tried to open the bombsquad game it does not run but after Three days it ran.

Comment: The first two commands would be meaningless jibberish to the system - both have obvious syntax errors. If that's what you really typed, then I'm not surprised that game didn't open. The third command also has an obvious syntax error, but the developers expected that particular use case so it would work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to install bombsquad.
First, open a terminal window.
Just download the game:

```
wget http://www.files.froemling.net/bombsquad/builds/BombSquad_Linux_64bit_1.4.147.tar.gz
```

Then extract the Archive:

```
tar -xf BombSquad_Linux_64bit_1.4.147.tar.gz
```

And now to start the game:

```
BombSquad_Linux_64bit_1.4.147/bombsquad
```

The game should now open in its own window

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way to install bombsquad on any version of ubuntu.

1. Install [snapd](https://snapcraft.io/) if you don't have it by running this command on your terminal `sudo apt install snapd`
2. Install bombsquad from snapd using your terminal by running this command `sudo snap install bombsquad`. about 70MB+ will be required
3. Bombsquad should now appear on your app list after completion